# executing in another thread|RuntimeError

Tags: ruby, multithreading, watir

I have something similar in my project

```
class Raj
  def execute
    5.times do
      Thread.new do
        object = Gopal.new
        object.db_connection
        object.enter_tax_id
      end
    end
  end
end

class Gopal
  def db_connection
    @db = "" # Created db connection here
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new
  end

  def enter_tax_id
    m = Mutex.new
    m.synchronize do
      data = @db_conn.select_one("select max(tax_id_no) from pcmp.tax_identifier")
      @browser.text_field(id: 'something').set 'data'
    end
  end
end
```

The enter tax id method pulls information from the database and then enters a value into the text field. This thread has an issue since other threads are interacting with it; when multiple threads attempt to execute the same procedure, a 'executing in another thread' error is raised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to resolve this issue, I used the following strategy:

```
class Gopal
  @mutex = Mutex.new
  def self.mutex_var
    @mutex
  end
  def db_connection
    @db = "" # Created db connection here
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new
  end

  def enter_tax_id
    Gopal.mutex_var.synchronize do
      data = @db.select_one("select max(tax_id)+1 from table")
      @browser.text_field(id: 'something').set 'data'
    end
  end
end
```

The mutex variable is now persistent as long as the class is loaded, thus even if another object is instantiated, the mutex variable will still be present and provide protection.